# Merging with more than one level overlap not allowed

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

So, I'm using pandas and essentially trying to calculate a normalized weight. For each day in my dataframe, I want the 'SECTOR' weight grouped by 'CAP', but they won't sum up to 1, so I want to normalize them as well. I thought I could accomplish this by dividing two groupbys, but I'm getting an error on my code that I don't quite understand. The code can run if I eliminate the 'CAP' in the second groupby.

Can anyone explain this to me?

```
df.groupby(['EFFECTIVE DATE','CAP','SECTOR'])['INDEX WEIGHT'].sum() / df.groupby(['EFFECTIVE DATE','CAP'])['INDEX WEIGHT'].sum()

NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented
```

Anybody know what I need to change? As always thank you!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Option 1***
Very close to what you had

```
cols = ['EFFECTIVE DATE', 'CAP', 'SECTOR', 'INDEX WEIGHT']
sector_sum = df.groupby(cols[:3])[cols[-1]].sum()
cap_sum = df.groupby(cols[:2])[cols[-1]].transform(pd.Series.sum).values
sector_sum / cap_sum
```

***Option 2***
Use a single `transform`

```
cols = ['EFFECTIVE DATE', 'CAP', 'SECTOR', 'INDEX WEIGHT']
sumto = lambda x: x / x.sum()
df.groupby(cols[:3])[cols[-1]].sum().groupby(level=cols[:2]).transform(sumto)
```

If you consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [0, 'Large', 'A', .1, 'a'],
        [0, 'Large', 'B', .2, 'b'],
        [0, 'Large', 'C', .1, 'c'],
        [0, 'Large', 'D', .3, 'd'],
        [0, 'Large', 'E', .1, 'e'],
        [0, 'Large', 'F', .4, 'f'],
        [0, 'Large', 'G', .1, 'g'],
        [0, 'Small', 'A', .2, 'h'],
        [0, 'Small', 'B', .3, 'i'],
        [0, 'Small', 'C', .4, 'j'],
        [0, 'Small', 'D', .5, 'k'],
        [0, 'Small', 'E', .1, 'l'],
        [0, 'Small', 'F', .2, 'm'],
        [0, 'Small', 'G', .1, 'n'],
        [1, 'Large', 'A', .1, 'a'],
        [1, 'Large', 'B', .2, 'b'],
        [1, 'Large', 'C', .1, 'c'],
        [1, 'Large', 'D', .3, 'd'],
        [1, 'Large', 'E', .1, 'e'],
        [1, 'Large', 'F', .4, 'f'],
        [1, 'Large', 'G', .1, 'g'],
        [1, 'Small', 'A', .2, 'h'],
        [1, 'Small', 'B', .3, 'i'],
        [1, 'Small', 'C', .4, 'j'],
        [1, 'Small', 'D', .5, 'k'],
        [1, 'Small', 'E', .1, 'l'],
        [1, 'Small', 'F', .2, 'm'],
        [1, 'Small', 'G', .1, 'n'],
    ], columns=['EFFECTIVE DATE', 'CAP', 'SECTOR', 'INDEX WEIGHT', 'ID'])
```

Both options produce

```
EFFECTIVE DATE  CAP    SECTOR
0               Large  A         0.076923
                       B         0.153846
                       C         0.076923
                       D         0.230769
                       E         0.076923
                       F         0.307692
                       G         0.076923
                Small  A         0.111111
                       B         0.166667
                       C         0.222222
                       D         0.277778
                       E         0.055556
                       F         0.111111
                       G         0.055556
1               Large  A         0.076923
                       B         0.153846
                       C         0.076923
                       D         0.230769
                       E         0.076923
                       F         0.307692
                       G         0.076923
                Small  A         0.111111
                       B         0.166667
                       C         0.222222
                       D         0.277778
                       E         0.055556
                       F         0.111111
                       G         0.055556
Name: INDEX WEIGHT, dtype: float64
```

If you assign one of the options to `df1` then sum the sub-groups

```
df1.groupby(level=['EFFECTIVE DATE', 'CAP']).sum()


EFFECTIVE DATE  CAP  
0               Large    1.0
                Small    1.0
1               Large    1.0
                Small    1.0
Name: INDEX WEIGHT, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Timing

[image]

Comment: @ piRSquared, thank you, your answers are always wonderful! If only I can know even half as much as you do... Quick follow up to this, how can I make sure that my original columns are intact when I do this? For me, it deleted one of my columns? (I am referring to your option 2, could not get option 1 to work) Thank you!